# ExtJs LoadMask inside modal dialog

Tags: image, extjs4, loading, mask

I'm trying to show loading mask while loading image inside the modal dialog in ExtJs. Problem is original mask disappears for the period of time while second mask is visible.

This is original screenshot. Modal dialog and background is masked:
[image: Original]

This is when I add second load mask for the image. 
[image: Loading image]

And then it goes back to first one. So the whole application background flicks pretty annoyingly. Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've test what you did. It doesn't flick for me. I think it's about **Z-Index** or **Unique ID** of masks. Try to track them with Firebug to see what exactly happens. For instance, some component come up to the mask. If you provide us some of your codes (simplified) we can do much with your problem.

Comment: Hm... Interesting. I will try to come up with minimal version to see what's going on. It's been all over my app and I just assumed it's a bug in ExtJs...

Comment: I had to table this question for now. Too busy with other stuff.